# Unknown column in 'where clause' failing in procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to run the following code in a procedure.  It is the very first line of code in the procedure after the `BEGIN`

```
update `deleteRequestsInitial` 
SET `mamaID` = (SELECT `id` FROM `love_users`
                WHERE `love_users`.`email` = `deleteRequestsInitial`.`Email`);
```

When I run it in the phpmyadmin SQL environment, it works fine.  But when I call the procedure, I get the error:

> Unknown column 'deleteRequestsInitial.Email' in 'where clause'

I've looked through a lot of the posts on the 'Unknown column' error, but none of the suggested workarounds seem to be working for me.

Comment: yes, but I did try both.

Comment: Can you try rewriting that using a join?      `UPDATE deleteRequestsInitial dri
    JOIN love_users lu ON lu.email = dri.Email    
    SET dri.mamaID = lu.id`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably really running this:

```
update `deleteRequestsInitial` 
SET `mamaID` = (SELECT `id` FROM `love_users`
                WHERE `love_users`.`email` = `deleteRequestsInitial.Email`);
```

Or possibly, the column is `email`, not `Email`.

I would suggest just dropping all the back ticks:

```
UPDATE deleteRequestsInitial dri
    SET mamaID = (SELECT id
                  FROM love_users lu
                  WHERE lu.email = dri.Email
                 );
```

Comment: Same error.  And yes, I'm sure on the case of `Email`;

Comment: @KristiPerkins . . . Then the column doesn't exist in `deleteRequestsInitial`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But why would it run fine in the phpmyadmin SQL environment? (OP mentioned in the question)

Comment: @PhilCoulson . . . Actually, the assumption would be that the two environments are connected to different databases.  Or possibly that one of them tweaks the query.